# c++ code (malloc method) to c# code

Tags: c#, c++, malloc, converters, printf

I have this c++ code and would convert it to c# (.net framework 4) code.
Has anyone some hints for me for the malloc, free and sprintf methods?

```
int monate = ee;
double *forward;
double *backward;
size_t bytes = 6*sizeof(double);
forward = (double *)malloc(monate * bytes);
backward = (double *)malloc(monate * bytes);

for (int i = 0; i <= monate; i++) {
    forward[i]   = 0.;
    backward[i]  = rate;
}

forward[0]        = auszahlungsbetrag;
backward[0]       = 0.;
backward[monate]  = rate + rest;

double ez =  esolver(12 , monate, forward, backward);
printf("Effektivzins: %.2f\n", ez);

char tmp0[256];
sprintf (tmp0, "Rate: %.2f (%f)" , rate, rate);
writeToLogFile(tmp0);

char tmp[256];
sprintf (tmp, "Effektivzins: %.2f (%f)" , ez, ez);
writeToLogFile(tmp);

free(forward);
free(backward);
```

Here is my converted c# code. For the methods malloc, free and sprintf i have some trouble to convert it to c#.

`using System;`

```
namespace Zinsrechner
{ 
public static class Basic
{

    public static void basic(double aa, double auszahlungsbetrag, double cc, int ee, double rest)
    {

        Writelog.writeToLogFile("Start der Berechnung, Type BASIC");
        Writelog.writeToLogFileDouble("Kreditvolumen: ", aa);
        Writelog.writeToLogFileDouble("Auszahlungsbetrag: ", auszahlungsbetrag);
        Writelog.writeToLogFileDouble("Nominalzins: ", cc);
        Writelog.writeToLogFileInt("Laufzeit: ", ee);
        Writelog.writeToLogFileDouble("Restschuld: ", rest);

        /////////

        // Ratenberechnung

        double nomzins = (cc / 12.0 / 100.0) + 1.0;
        double unten = 0.0;

        for (int x = 0 ; x <= ee-1 ; x++)
        {
            unten = unten + Math.Pow(nomzins,x);
        }

        double rate = ((aa * Math.Pow(nomzins, ee)) - rest) / unten;
        Console.Write("Rate: {0:f2}\n", rate);

        int monate = ee;
        double[] forward;
        double[] backward;
        uint bytes = 6 * sizeof(double);
        //C++ TO C# CONVERTER TODO TASK: The memory management function 'malloc' has no equivalent in C#:
        //forward = (double)malloc(monate * bytes);
        forward = (double)(monate * bytes);
        //C++ TO C# CONVERTER TODO TASK: The memory management function 'malloc' has no equivalent in C#:
        backward = (double)malloc(monate * bytes);

        for (int i = 0; i <= monate; i++)
        {
            forward[i] = 0.0;
            backward[i] = rate;
        }

        forward[0] = auszahlungsbetrag;
        backward[0] = 0.0;
        backward[monate] = rate + rest;

        double ez = Effektivzinssolver.esolver(12, monate, forward, backward);
        Console.Write("Effektivzins: {0:f2}\n", ez);

        string tmp0 = new string(new char[256]);
        tmp0 = string.Format("Rate: {0:f2} ({1:f})", rate, rate);
        Writelog.writeToLogFile(tmp0);

        string tmp = new string(new char[256]);
        tmp = string.Format("Effektivzins: {0:f2} ({1:f})", ez, ez);
        Writelog.writeToLogFile(tmp);

        //C++ TO C# CONVERTER TODO TASK: The memory management function 'free' has no equivalent in C#:
        free(forward);
        //C++ TO C# CONVERTER TODO TASK: The memory management function 'free' has no equivalent in C#:
        free(backward);


    }
}
}
```

Comment: That's not C++ code, that's C code.

Comment: @Angew It's not as if the code here wasn't valid C++. Why, I always thought "C++" referred to the whole language, not just the parts that aren't in classic C.

Comment: @user3109672 OK, true. But still, converting idiomatic C++ code to C# will follow a vastly different course from converting this "C with a novelty file extension" code to C#.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalents to malloc and free are:

```
IntPtr memory = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(100); //malloc
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(memory); //free
```

Comment: While true, I think this is not very helpful in this case, since you don't need to do any manual memory management in C# for this example.

Answer (score 1):

```
double[] forward = new double[monate * 6];
```

You don't need to `free()`. C# is garbage collected.

Answer (score 1):

In C# you do not need to care of memory - garbage collector copes with it great. Your code has to be something like this:

```
int monate = ee;
double[] forward = new double[monate * 6];
double[] backward = new double[monate * 6];

for (int i = 0; i <= monate; i++) {
    forward[i]   = 0.;
    backward[i]  = rate;
}

forward[0]        = auszahlungsbetrag;
backward[0]       = 0;
backward[monate]  = rate + rest;

double ez =  esolver(12 , monate, forward, backward);
Console.WriteLine("Effektivzins: {0}\n", ez);
```

And then, do not name variables with Deutsch and English together ;)

Comment: You are lecturing the poor fellow without answering his question. What if he really wants to do the equivalent of malloc/free where he then manages the life cycle of the memory?

Answer (score 0):

You can forget about `Malloc` and `Free` since C# has a Garbage Collector. As for `sprintf` take a look at [String.Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [Console.WriteLine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/zdf6yhx5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also, since it looks like your application seems to deal with money amounts, I would highly recommend to use the `decimal` type instead of `double`. ([decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/364x0z75%28v=vs.90%29.aspx))